# Trying to generate TLS keys for Postfix OPENSSL debian squeeze

Tags: debian, openssl, debian-squeeze

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -key server.key -out lawson.csr
openssl ca -out lawson.pem -infiles server.csr
```

I'm trying to generate key's and crt's for postfix, but every time when I want to do the certifaction authority part it gives me this error :

```
Using configuration from /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
Error opening CA private key ./demoCA/private/cakey.pem
29899:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:356:fopen('./demoCA/private/cakey.pem','r')
29899:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:358:
```

I've tried using CA.sh -newca but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you *have* a CA key generated already?  If not, you might want to [generate one](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=openssl+generate+CA+key).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a serial for your CA (it's just a counter that increments each time you sign with CA): http://bookmarks.honewatson.com/2008/05/08/error-opening-ca-private-key-democaprivatecakeypem/